# ADAM Gradient descent oscillates close to minimum

Tags: optimization, algorithms, gradient-descent, extreme-value, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am using [ADAM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf) as an optimization algorithm to minimize some black box function $f(x,y)$. I know this function is convex and has a minimum $f(5,5) = 0$.

Initially, the algorithm proceeds as expected:

[image]

where the $x$ and $y$ axis are the respective variables, and the red dot indicates the target of $x=5, y=5$

However at small values of $f(x,y)$ I get,

[image]

This is a problem if I want convergence to zero within some precision $\epsilon \ \sim 10^{-12}$.

**What is the cause of oscillations like this?**

**What is a solution to avoid/compensate for them?**

Answer (score 5):

> What is the cause of oscillations like this?

SGD (with and without momentum) can naturally have oscillations. This is largely due to *high curvature areas of the objective landscape*. In particular, especially with momentum present, gradient descent behaves like a damped harmonic oscillator.

Some references:

- [Goh, *Why Momentum Really Works*](https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/)
- [Lucas et al, *Aggregated Momentum: Stability Through Passive Damping*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00325)
- [Yang et al, *The Physical Systems Behind Optimization
  Algorithms*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02803)

> What is a solution to avoid/compensate for them?

One answer is to correct for this curvature, which is presumably high near the minimum. The first reference above suggests tuning the gradient descent hyper-parameters. Another option, depending on your situation (mostly the size of the model and the inherent noise in the gradient estimates), it may be possible to use *second-order* optimization methods instead, such as the [natural gradient](https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/089976698300017746) (see also [KFAC](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05671)) or Newton's method (e.g. see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03662), but also see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253632/why-is-newtons-method-not-widely-used-in-machine-learning)).