# Loss function in machine learning - how to constrain?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, loss-functions

My loss has two parts, say L1 and L2. I want to minimize both, and at the same time I need to constrain that L1 should be always greater than L2 (L1>L2). Is the following correct?

loss = L2 - L1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This isn't **exactly** what you've asked for, but it's a very easy solution to implement in neural network libraries like keras, tensorflow and pytorch.

The main idea is to penalize the loss whenever the inequality $L_1 > L_2$ is violated. This inequality is violated whenever $L_2 \ge L_1$;on the other hand, we don't want to penalize the loss at all when $L_1 > L_2$.  This describes a ReLU function in $L_1, L_2$:

$$
\min L_1 + L_2 + \lambda\text{ReLU}(L_2 - L_1)
$$

The hyper-parameter $\lambda>0$ controls how steep the penalty should be for violating the inequality.

This loss doesn't guarantee that the inequality is satisfied, but it is an improvement over minimizing $L_1 + L_2$ alone.

This loss is just a composition of functions readily available in modern neural network libraries, so it's simple to implement.

In comments, [jkpate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/157922/jkpate) makes the following suggestion:

> Notice that if you incorporate a maximization over $\lambda$, then we do get exactly what the poster asked for because we now have a two-player formulation of the Lagrange dual to the original constrained optimization problem. Essentially, rather than setting $\lambda$ be fixed, we allow the penalty for a violation to grow. See [Cotter et al. "Two-Player Games for Efficient Non-Convex Constrained Optimization" (2019)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v98/cotter19a.html) for the theory and https://github.com/google-research/tensorflow_constrained_optimization for a Tensorflow implementation.

If I understand correctly, this allows the estimation procedure to select a good value of $\lambda$, rather than the user fixing a particular value ahead of time and worrying about whether that fixed value is a good choice.

Comment: This is pretty much what I would think of as well, though I was typing up $RELU(L_2 - L_1)^2$ as the penalty term. I've done this in practice for constrained minimization problems. It's a bit fussy, but can work out.

Comment: @MatthewDrury it might be worth adding your answer just because I’m interested in understanding why you prefer to square it. I’ve never used a loss like this so I’m just spitballing.

Comment: Notice that if you incorporate a maximization over $\lambda$, then we do get exactly what the poster asked for because we now have a two-player formulation of the Lagrange dual to the original constrained optimization problem. Essentially, rather than setting $\lambda$ be fixed, we allow the penalty for a violation to grow. See [Cotter et al. (2019)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v98/cotter19a.html) for the theory and https://github.com/google-research/tensorflow_constrained_optimization for a tensorflow implementation.

Comment: @jkpate This is a good find! I can edit my answer to add this, but on the other hand, I think if you wrote an answer summarizing these findings, you'd get several upvotes. I know you'd get one from me.

Answer (score 12):

That will likely give you unexpected results. Minimizing your loss will incentivize your algorithm to minimize L2, but to *maximize* L1. There is no incentive to *minimize* L1.

It sounds like you have a constraint minimization problem: minimize L1+L2, subject to L1>L2. This is very common in optimization software, but less so in ML fitting software. You will likely need to feed this into your modeler in some tool-specific way, if such a constraint can be modeled at all.

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not correct. If you want to minimize both, definitely you should write L1+L2, but not L2-L1.

This is because in L2-L1, we can always make L1 to be huge (maximize L1) to make the final loss small.

The problem can be formulated to

$$\text{minimze} ~~L_1+L_2$$
$$\text{st.}~ L_2 -L_1 >0$$

And in many case, if we want to emphasize one loss than another we can use a weighted sum where

$$\text{minimze} ~~\alpha L_1+ (1-\alpha)L_2$$

Answer (score 2):

I would try to follow the [Kuhn-Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) problem setup for inequality constrained optimization. Here's how its objective is set as a Lagrangian:
$$L(x,\lambda)=L_1(x)+L_2(x)+\lambda(L_2(x)-L_1(x))$$

You need to find a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) where $\nabla L=0$, then $x$ will be the optimum. Normally, in optimization we don't like saddle points though, because they're not optima. However, in this case we're optimizing both $x$ and $\lambda$, not just $x$, so the saddle point is what we need.

Maybe experiment with Newton's method optimizer in your Neural Net. Unlike some other optimizers, such as SGD, this one is [attracted to saddle points](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/301728/36041). I like @Sycorax answer where he uses ReLU. However, I believe than Kuhn-Tucker lagrangian will be more efficient if you manage to convine your NN that saddle points are Ok. The reason being is that ReLU will have a flat gradient everywhere where $L_1>L_2$, so the speed convergence must be relatively lower. At the same type ReLU is obviously a no brainer to setup in any NN.