# Gradient Descent vs Newton's Method?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

Can someone please elaborate on Gradient Descent vs Newton's Method? I am studying for my ML exam tomorrow and saw this as a bullet point but cannot find many great answers. Can anyone fill me in some details on the both of these, as deep as you would like to go.

Comment: There is some discussion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization
And here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253632/why-is-newtons-method-not-widely-used-in-machine-learning?rq=1

Comment: You can also have a look at Andrew's Ng lecture notes on supervised learning (paragraph 7) : http://cs229.stanford.edu/syllabus.html